# Javascript color picker with 8 digit hex

Tags: javascript, hash, hex, color-picker

I'm looking for a javascript color picker, with which I can set color and opacity. The returned string has to be an 8 digit long hex value (excluding the #).

Already had a look at

- Farbtastic http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/
- jPicker http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/
- jQuery Minicolors http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-miniColors/

and many others. But none of them gives me what I want, I don't want to mess with trimming strings etc. because the color picker has to be implemented about a 100 times on one page to realise a skinning editor.

**EDIT**

http://jscolor.com/

This is how it looks like using JSColor:

http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/3962/unbenannt3op.png

And this is the code, with which I get and set the hexcode in my bean:

```
<h:inputText styleClass="color {hash:true}"
             value="#{skinningBean.currentSkin.titleBar.backgroundColorStart}">
<a4j:ajax event="change" render="preview" />
```

This would be working perfectly fine, except for the missing alpha values (last 2 digits).

Comment: Do you mean a 6 digit hex value? RRGGBB

Comment: No, 8 digits: RRGGBBAA

Comment: AA = Alpha... @George Mickleburg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a public domain color picker in JavaScript. As you requested, I've now added a feature that shows a color in the format RRGGBBAA, with hexadecimal components.

- Demo: http://peteroupc.github.com/colorpicker/ (Look at the example "Alpha Color Picker (RRGGBBAA format)".)
- Source code: https://github.com/peteroupc/colorpicker

To enable this feature, give the text boxes an ID starting with "rgbahex_", as in this example:

```
<input type="text" value="ff0000ff" name="c2" id="rgbahex_c2">
```

By doing so, the text box will be converted into a color picker. It will only work, though, if the input box appears in the HTML before the page is fully loaded. If you're creating color pickers at runtime, use the following JavaScript to set it up:

```
textbox.value="ff0000ff";
PDColorPicker.setColorPicker(textbox,{rgbahex:true});
```

`setColorPicker` will also convert the text box to a color picker.

---

I've updated the color picker to add the colorformat AARRGGBB. Use `argbhex` instead of `rgbahex` in the examples above.

You can also start a text box's class name with "rgbahex_", "argbhex_", and so on, rather than the ID, to turn, to turn the text box into a color picker. I *think* this corresponds to the `styleClass` attribute in your XML.

Comment: Would it also be possible to make AARRGGBB available? If it isn't much effort. Although my sepcs changed a bit :/ Otherwise I'll have to swap the Strings in my Bean

Comment: Yes, of course. I will add it as soon as possible. Watch this space.

Comment: And I have another issue, concerning the id has to begin with this id. Because I'm using JSF and a4j events I can only use <h:inputText> instead of input. So maybe it just can contain this id? :)

Comment: Btw... I don't get what your homepage is about T_T

Comment: One last thing:
I need to listen to the onchange event for the input, but it seems you handle it intern so my a4j doesn't get called. Can you tell me how to fix it? I tried to change your javascript a bit and call thisInput.onchange(); but it won't help.

Comment: Nevermind, I got this. Added    document.activeElement.onchange() to your documentMouseUp function :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why it's not easier to find, but [spectrum](http://bgrins.github.com/spectrum/) has everything I ever needed in a color picker.  (I was using minicolors until I found spectrum.)

I don't know if it takes 8 digit hex, but I know it will accept 4 parameter rgba.  (It uses a plugin called [tinycolor](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor) for all the color parsing.)

Comment: I will have a look at it :) If it turns out it's working I'm going to accept your answer

Comment: If you're still interested in using spectrum, it doesn't currently support hex8, but you can easily add it with two blocks of copy-paste.  Just search for hex6 in the code, then copy and modify the blocks (at this time, lines 813 and 852) that use a regex.

Comment: I had a look at it right now and I can't take spectrum, because an <f:ajax> or <a4j:ajax> tag is not supported for a simple input tag.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to manage it by defining a "trim strings and do this thing" function that would only have to be implemented once, and just call it everywhere.

Comment: As I have a Bean running in background and many other stuff, this is not the answer I'm looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the spectrum color picker that Scott suggested, but then you could get the RGB value from it, and use this property:

```
background: rgba(132,182,19,.5);
```

That way, it will set the background of the current div and it will be as opaque as you want (so you'll have to find a way to give it the opacity you want), but then at least you'll get the color values from the picker.  If you want more information on fallbacks, and workarounds for IE on using rgba, look at [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/).

Update:

Try something like this, if you have to use hex values instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/WzGG6/1/

Comment: The problem is I'm reading the values from an XML file in the format #RRGGBBAA and also have to write it to this XML in the same format, to make it readable for several clients (android, iOs, etc)

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a jsfiddle that you could use for using hex colors instead of the rgba background property.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing this... but where are they even choosing the opacity for these colors?  Your code looks to me like you could just set an opacity (so after your {skinningBean.currentSkin.titleBar.backgroundColorStart}, just put 2 numbers).  Otherwise, if they can choose it in a separate field, you could just append that.  Am I missing this completely?

Comment: They aren't yet, that's the problem ;)
TIght now I just set the 6 digit long hex code with the hash. (e.g. #ffffff) That's why I'm looking for an alternative.
If you have a look at the picture I posted you'll get it I guess

Comment: So could you just give the opacity a default value, and then add a field so they could also set that, but separately from the color (then you either append the default, or what they picked)??  I saw the picture, but I haven't ever seen a color & opacity picker in the same tool to return an 8 digit hex...

Answer (score 0):

// I’ve been using this component for my projects:

```
<html>
<script src="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.js"></script>
<script src="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />
<jsuites-color value="#009688"></jsuites-color>
<script>
document.querySelector('jsuites-color').addEventListener('onchange', function(e) {
    // Set the font color
    e.target.children[0].style.color = this.value;
    // Show on console
    console.log('New value:' + this.value);
});
</script>
</html>
```

// Here's the link if you want to check it out: https://jsuites.net/docs/color-picker